How to override 'Edit' action with LWC Modal?
I understand an LWC record action cannot directly be used to override a standard action like 'new' or 'edit'. I've referred to a blog  which invokes a LightningModal LWC from an Aura component. Based on that, I've set up following:

Aura Component to override the 'new' and 'edit' actions
LWC Container element which invokes the Modal
LWC LighningModal containing the modal I want to display

I wanted the modal to open up when the Aura component loads but it fails to do so
My Aura Component
    <aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName"
    access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init"
        value="{!this}"
        action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <c:lwcContainer recordId="{!v.recordId}"
        aura:id="testModal"></c:lwcContainer>
    <lightning:button variant="brand"
        label="Test Modal"
        onclick="{!c.openTestModal}"
        class="slds-m-around_x-small">
    </lightning:button>
    Test
</aura:component>

Aura Controller:
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        console.log('Aura Loaded');
        let testModal = component.find('testModal');
        console.log('Modal Component : ', testModal);
        testModal.lwcModal();
    },
    openTestModal : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('opentestmodal')
        let testModal = component.find('testModal');
        console.log('Test modal in open : ', testModal)
        testModal.lwcModal();
    }
})

In the LWC's controller
@api
    async lwcModal(mode) {
        console.log('Modal : ', mode);
        const result = await newLWCModal.open({
            // label is not included here in this example.
            // it is set on lightning-modal-header instead
            size: 'large',
            description: 'Accessible description of modal\'s purpose',
            recordId: this.recordId,
        });

        if (result) {
            this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
        }
    }

When I invoke this action from the 'Edit' action, I see 'test' and the button on the screen. However, the modal doesn't auto launch.
On clicking the button, the modal loads up correctly.
What am I doing wrong here ?

has the LWC been rendered when called in the doInit function?

@NickC the component has no markup in it as it is created just to open the modal on load
